# Conflicts cause by MooTools for MooWheel

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to use MooWheel but MooTools 1.2, on which it depends, is causing problems to the rest of my JS libraries.

Could I somehow use the MooTools 1.6.0?

Comment: Is this the plugin https://github.com/pokeball99/moowheel? MooWheel seems to not be updated since 2008. Maybe its not too much change to make it 1.6 compatible.

Comment: I realized that the problem is caused by conflicts between MooTools and jQuery. However I don't get any error messages and if I use the 'jQuery.noConflict();', things get even worse..